# else if condition while comparing 2 variables in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php so far i wrote this referral script:

```
<?php
ob_start();
include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php' );
mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
$id = $_REQUEST['id']; 
$uid = $_REQUEST['uid']; 
$oid = $_REQUEST['oid'];
$new = $_REQUEST['new']; 
$total = $_REQUEST['total'];
$sig = $_REQUEST['sig'];

// Secrete Key
$hash = 'myapikey';

// Output results
if ($sig == $hash) {


//Users point update query here  (it's working )
 $users = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM users WHERE id=".$uid);
 $rows = mysql_fetch_array($users);
 $user_points = $rows['points'];
 $query1 = mysql_query("update users set points=($user_points+$new) where id=".$uid );

//Updating referral coins (it's not working )
        $query2 = ("SELECT points, referral_id, level FROM users WHERE referral_id=".$uid );    
        $user_rows = mysql_query($query2);
        $all=mysql_fetch_array($user_rows,MYSQL_BOTH);
        if($all['referral_id'] != 0 && $all['level'] == 0){
             $lvl0 = $new*(15/100);
             $referal_points = $lvl0;
             $update_referral_points = ("update users set points = points + $referal_points where referral_id = ".$all['referral_id']);
             mysql_query($update_referral_points);

        } else if($all['referral_id'] != 0 && $all['level'] == 1){
             $lvl1 = $new*(25/100);
             $referal_points = $lvl1;
             $update_referral_points = ("update users set points = points + $referal_points where referral_id = ".$all['referral_id']);
             mysql_query($update_referral_points);

        }
            print "1\n";
        } else {
            print "0\n";
}
?>
```

How Script working: 
whenever someone signup using referral code i have insert referral code user id into new user referral_id row, & through $_REQUEST['']; my app sending points ($new) to user...
$query1 is working fine there's problem to execute $query2, in short $query2 needs to be fixed; something getting wrong, that i am not able to figure out if any pro can help me out this i will appreciate it...

DB structure:

```
users table:
  id (AI)      name      points     Referral code     Referral id   Level
=========== ========== ========== ================== ============== ======
     1        user A       0          abcdef123             0         0
     2        user B      100         bvsuda897             1         1
     3        user C      500         vrtasio65             2         0
```

> In this example above,

1- **user C** signup using **user B Referral code = bvsuda897**

2- right now **user B level is 1** so whenever **user C earn point ($new)** my app should give u**ser B 25% coins** of **user C $new**

> The Problem
>   right now when my app sending coins to user C, user B not getting coins, because something wrong in query2

Comment: MySQL_* is now deprecated. Look into using PDO or MySQLI instead

Comment: @Option, i am not really sure about it sir, can you please rewrite where changes required :)

Comment: anything using mysql_ queries. Take a look at PDO you'll find it pretty easy to use and it's very good.

Comment: alright i am looking into information, can you just confirm is query 2 syntax & code all fine as per my requirement, so i just head up to replace mysql_ queries Cheers !

Comment: @Option sir i have been read it's not just because of mysql_query deprecation, one of my query already working well with mysql => $query1 = mysql_query,  there's problem with $query2,

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your `$query2`, instead I believe your problem is likely in the code afterwards. I would suggest using `var_dump()` to output the contents of $all, because I have a feeling it is in a different format than you are expecting. Sorry I don't have a direct answer, but that is a place to start your debugging.

Comment: @Gwellin, frankly speaking; i have basic knowledge of php & i don't know how to do this, could you please answer something so i can try if working ?

Comment: @Gwellin, i tried > var_dump($all); & get Result Reply: 1 bool(false) have i did correct & what is next step?

Comment: `var_dump();` is a method to output variable information. If you got a `bool(false)`, that means `mysql_fetch_array()` failed, and the following `if` `else` won't find the array keys. Try dumping `$user_rows`, and researching `mysql_fetch_array()`. I'm sorry but I'm not experienced enough with those functions without testing the code myself. But as Option said, you are using deprecated functions which will eventually stop working after PHP updates.

Comment: @gwellin, i got it now, will try "option" suggestion once we done with error tracing, i did this var_dump($user_rows); now getting result = 1 resource(5) of type (mysql result) what's next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some more time looking over your code, I have tracked down your issue. First, you need to get the `referral_id` from the `$users` query.

```
$users = mysql_query("SELECT points, referral_id FROM users WHERE id=".$uid);
```

Then `$query2` needs to match the `id` to the user's `referral_id`, not the other way around.

```
$query2 = "SELECT id, points, referral_id, level FROM users WHERE id=".$rows['referral_id'];
```

Your `UPDATE` queries may need some work after that, but this will get you in to the `if` `else` conditions.

---

**Successful code determined by OP**

```
//Updating referral coins
$query2 = "SELECT id, points, referral_id, level FROM users WHERE id=".$rows['referral_id']; $user_rows = mysql_query($query2);
$all=mysql_fetch_array($user_rows,MYSQL_BOTH);
$lvl0 = intval((5/100) * $new);
$lvl1 = intval((10/100) * $new);
$query3 = mysql_query("update users set points = (points + $lvl0) where level = 0 AND referral_id = ".$all['referral_id']);
$query4 = mysql_query("update users set points = (points + $lvl1) where level = 1 AND referral_id = ".$all['referral_id']);
```

---

Now I appreciate that you are in the learning stage, but I want to point out a couple things that will cause confusions as you pursue PHP programming in the future.

First off, as Option mentioned, the MySQL functions you are using have been deprecated. They do not exist in the current stable version of PHP, and your code will no longer work if the server is updated. Look in to [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) as alternatives. It's a lot to learn, but some Googling will get you some guidance.

Second is your use of `$_REQUEST`, which combines the values of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`, allowing easy manipulation by visitors. It may be that you are only using it for the user details while testing your other code, but I just want to make sure you know about [PHP sessions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), which is the better way to store a relationship between a logged in user and their persistent variables.

Comment: i appreciate your time on this script, i am going to try it, regarding php my hosting "php version" is still on 5.4 native, i need to keep on $_REQUEST because data is coming in form of request through " API"

Comment: i love to learn now things, but right now i am in hurry, i have tried above but not working, please tell me where to use $users ?

Comment: The two lines of code I supplied are meant to replace the similar lines in your code, where you define `$users` and `$query2`, respectively. If you're seeing any error messages, please post them.

Comment: replaced / done and tested, **but user B  still not get point **, but now start getting results when i **var_dump($all)** Result: 1 array(8) { [0]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "0" ["points"]=> string(1) "0" [2]=> string(1) "0" ["referral_id"]=> string(1) "0" [3]=> string(1) "1" ["level"]=> string(1) "1" like this, what's next sir you almost made it Cheers !

Comment: This is a case where I feel error messages would really help. My best guess is that your `$update_referral_points` queries need parentheses when setting `points`, but I'm not certain. `$update_referral_points = ("update users set points = (points + $referal_points) where referral_id = ".$all['referral_id']);`

Comment: Try replacing the two lines you define `$update_referral_points` with the code block in my last comment. If you are still having issues I suggest turning on [`error_reporting`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) or tracking down the `error.log` file, which would help a great deal.

Comment: finally found problem here var_dump ($referal_points); result = null any help on this

Comment: also tried this = //$referal_points = "12"; but still getting " Null " result var_dump ($referal_points); ? it's really strange

Comment: The only way `$referral_points` could be `null` is if you either typoed the variable (how many r's?) or put your `var_dump()` before it is set.

Comment: after tried many ways i am now able to update referral user point by doing this 
`//Updating referral coins 
  $query2 = "SELECT id, points, referral_id, level FROM users WHERE id=".$rows['referral_id'];
  //$query2 = "select points, referral_id from users where referral_id=".$uid; 
  $user_rows = mysql_query($query2);
  $all=mysql_fetch_array($user_rows,MYSQL_BOTH);
  $referal_points = intval((25/100) * $new);
  $query3 = mysql_query("update users set points = (points + $referal_points) where referral_id = ".$all['referral_id']);`

Comment: `/*
  if($all['referral_id'] != 0 && $all['level'] == 0){
      $referal_points = intval((25/100) * $new);
      $update_referral_points = ("update users set points = (points + $referal_points) where referral_id = ".$all['referral_id']);
    mysql_query($update_referral_points);

     }
   */
   //var_dump ($all)
   
   //var_dump ($referal_points); // it's not working
   
   //var_dump ($update_referral_points); */ `

Comment: **now please help me out to add if else conditions **

Comment: i learned alot from you, please edit your answer with new code, along with conditions, cheers!

Comment: i think we don't need to put $referal_points = intval((25/100) * $new); before our condition i am going to declare it like this $lvl0 = intval((5/100) * $new); $lvl1 = intval((10/100) * $new); $query3 = mysql_query("update users set points = (points + $lvl0 ) where referral_id = ".$all['referral_id']);

Comment: instead of condition i did some logical operations

Comment: **here is 100% working**
`//Updating referral coins 
  $query2 = "SELECT id, points, referral_id, level FROM users WHERE id=".$rows['referral_id']; 
  $user_rows = mysql_query($query2);
  $all=mysql_fetch_array($user_rows,MYSQL_BOTH);
  $lvl0 = intval((5/100) * $new);
  $lvl1 = intval((10/100) * $new);
  $query3  = mysql_query("update users set points = (points + $lvl0) where level = 0 AND referral_id = ".$all['referral_id']);
  $query4  = mysql_query("update users set points = (points + $lvl1) where level = 1 AND referral_id = ".$all['referral_id']);`

Comment: add it in your answer i want to accept your answer to appreciate your time & efforts and share to world

Comment: I'm glad that you figured it all out. I know how satisfying it can be to finally fix code like this. I added the lines to my answer.

Comment: yup, i have learned debugging from you, now i will spend some time to learn "option's " suggestion.... cheers!